# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') at handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

`handleSubmit` function and it is called inside the form
it is a false error, though the values are still getting saved in the Mongo.
I've tried different ways  to call the `handleSubmit` function as
`<form onsubmit{()=>handleSubmit()>`
this way it shows the error &quickly removes it but it doesn't save the values

```js
async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        await fetchSetupDetails();

        // Access form data
        const setupName = event.target.elements.setupName.value;
        const ipElements = event.target.querySelectorAll('.ip');
        const typeElements = event.target.querySelectorAll('[id^="type-"]');
        // Create an array of IP objects
        const setupIPs = Array.from(ipElements).map((ipElement, index) => ({
            ip: ipElement.value,
            type: typeElements[index].value
        }));
        const setupLocation = event.target.elements.setup_location.value;
        const setupOwner = event.target.elements.setup_owner.value;
        ...//more code


    const modifiedTeamName = `${rat}-${teamName}`;
        const data = {
            setupName,
            setupIPs,
            //
        };

        try {
            const response = await axios.put(`http://${configData.ip}:${configData.port}/detail`, data);
            const pod_response = await axios.post(`http://${configData.ip}:${configData.port}/pod_detail`,formData);
            event.target.reset();
            navigate('/');
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };


return(
        <form className="centered-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

Comment: when you are trying to call the function this way: `onSubmit={()=>handleSubmit()` you need to pass the event argument: `onSubmit={(event)=>handleSubmit(event)` .

Comment: Tried it, but the same problm occurs. Instead of navigating and resetting the values, it remains on same page.

Comment: event.preventDefault();   remove this line

Comment: @Aarav also looking the error, it says that something with .value is undefined. i wuold suggest you to do console.log with anything with .value at the end and figure out which one is undefined. this will give you the idea what you should address.